# Sinon stub argument return fake callback

Tags: sinon

I just want to know if it is possible to fake a callback on a stub argument.

This is basically what I want to achieve and I found nothing on Sinon's documentation:

```
function A(arg1, arg2, next){

    return [arg1, arg2, next];
};

function B(string){
    return string;
};

function C(){
    return 'Mocked next';
};

var obj = {
    A: A,
    test: 'test'
};

var result1 = obj.A(1, 2, B('Next')); // result1 = [1, 2, 'Next']

sandbox.stub(obj, 'A')//.Argument[2].Returns(C());

var result2 = obj.A(1, 2, B('Next')); // result2 = [1, 2, 'Mocked next']
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test ?

Comment: Does it matter? I need that all arguments to be the same except that one. It's a simplified version of a chain of functions being called.

Comment: why not just mock `function B` to return mocked value.

Comment: because it is a callback function, it is not a fixed function. I need to mock that argument..

Comment: I not sure if there is any way to do what you want.  Please explain the scenario, may be I can help then ? And in your example, you are not using `function B` as a callback.  It's a simple function that returns a value.

Comment: It is a simplified version...just make it simple, is it possible to force a stub to use another function besides the one that its passed?

Comment: I don't understand your example. You are testing `function A`, but you have stubbed your `function A`.  So, the real function will never be called.  You are saying it's chain of  functions, but I don't see any chain or callback function your example.
Please provide more  information & example.

Comment: By the way, you are not passing function B as argument in `obj.A(1, 2, B('Next'))`, it's the value returned by `function B`.
To pass `function B` as argument, you have to write `obj.A(1, 2, () => B('Next'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

`sinon` doesn't provide a way to directly mock an argument of a `stub`, but it does provide `callsFake` which lets you create your own implementation.

You can create a `stub` that calls the original implementation with the result of `C()` passed as the third argument like this:

```js
const original = obj.A;  // capture original obj.A
sandbox.stub(obj, 'A').callsFake((...args) => original(args[0], args[1], C()));

const result = obj.A(1, 2, B('Next'));
sinon.assert.match(result, [1, 2, 'Mocked next']);  // SUCCESS
```